# Security-checker error when deploying Symfony 4 app to Google App Engine

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, composer-php

Deploying Symfony 4 app to Google App Engine (Flex) with gcloud app deploy.

Build fails after installing dependencies:

```
Step #1: Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Step #1: Executing script assets:install public [OK]
Step #1: Executing script security-checker security:check [KO]
Step #1: [KO]
Step #1: Script security-checker security:check returned with error code 127
Step #1: !! sh: 1: security-checker: not found
Step #1: !! 
Step #1: Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 127
Finished Step #1
ERROR
```

And my composer "scripts" looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
        "security-checker security:check": "script"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
}
```

I ran composer update before deploying and warmed up the cache for prod env.

Why is the build failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your security check setup is not OK:

- this is relevant config line:

> ```
>    "security-checker security:check": "script"
> ```

- these are the log lines showing the corresponding invocation failed:

> ```
> Step #1: Executing script security-checker security:check [KO]
> Step #1: [KO]
> Step #1: Script security-checker security:check returned with error code 127
> ```

Meaning the command that was attempted and failed was `security-checker security:check`. The actual failure reason is revealed in the subsequent line:

> ```
> Step #1: !! sh: 1: security-checker: not found
> ```

Meaning that the shell couldn't find a suitable `security-checker` executable. There could be multiple reasons for that, including problems with the script itself or with the execution environment, for example:

- the script wasn't yet created
- the script actually has a different name
- the script's location isn't in the execution path, so its path needs to be specified as well, not just its filename (or the script's dir needs to be included in the execution path).

To fix the build you could:

- comment/take out the corresponding config line
- correct the config line if it's wrong, for example if it's not matching the actual environment
- adjust the environment to match the config (if the config is deemed correct for the intended usage).